# Customizing selection behavior of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm implementing custom visual effects when the user selects a row in a `UITableView`.  I've overridden `UITableViewCell.setSelected()`, but I call it in my subclass, it does some tweaking of the appearance of the content view before adding the `selectedBackgroundView` to the hierarchy, like setting opacity to false.  I don't want the content view and it's subviews to be !opaque, so I thought I could avoid calling `super.setSelected` when overriding it, but then that breaks the select/deselect behavior.

- Is there a way to avoid the default `UI` changes of `UITableViewCell.setSelected()` without breaking cell `selection/deselection`? It is surprising to me that built in UI changes for `selecting/deselecting` cells is so intertwined with the logic/state tracking to make `selection/deselection` work at all inside `setSelected()`
- More generally, are there any debugging tips or tracing I can use to see what exactly goes on, in terms of what updates are happening to views, when calling something like `UITableViewCell.setSelected()`, so I can mimic it without calling the base class method (I understand this is likely to break with new versions of iOS)

Thank you,

Neal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the cell selection method you can try using the highlight method.

**Step 1:** Make the table view cell selection to none

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

**Step 2:** Override the cell's set highlighted method to customize the cell selection

```
 - (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
          if (highlighted) 
          {
          }
          else
          {
          }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the information!  This appears to work, with some caveats.   From my experimentation, setHighlighted is called twice when a cell is selected:  first with "true" and second with "false" for the first parameter. So, the highlight provided by setHighlighted isn't for the final UI state of a selected cell, but for UI effects "on the way" to a cell being selected.  The tip about the selection style has removed the unwanted opacity tweaks for me though - thank you! Will accept the answer.